Solution of a Second order Partial Differential Equation
In the following IBVP after finding the general solution, by substituting the initial conditions I tried to find $\displaystyle \large c_{5nm}$ and $\large \displaystyle c_{6nm}$ finding the latter is pretty straightforward as it's equal to zero but finding $\large \displaystyle c_{5nm}$ is what caused me confusion because I cannot seem to find a double Fourier series that is equivalent to my solution of the PDE. Also, the solution that the textbook provided caused me further confusion as to how the double summation reduced to a single summation and how $\displaystyle \sin(m\pi y)$ transformed to $\sin(n\pi y)$ in the solution, I will appreciate it if someone could provide me with the logic and reasoning behind this? I appreciate any help you can provide.
(Note: in the process of solving the PDE the coefficients that was created after solving the Sturm-Lioville problems and the coefficient of the linear combination are assumed to be one)

This is my solution to the problem:
$$
\begin{gather}
\boxed{ \displaystyle
u(x,y,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigg[c_{5nm}\cos(\overbrace{\omega_{nm}}^{c\pi \sqrt{ n^2+m^2 }}t)+c_{6nm}\sin(\omega_{nm}t)\bigg]\sin(n\pi x)\sin(m\pi y)}\\ \\
\text{I used IC's for finding coefficients }\, c_{5nm}\text{and}\,c_{6nm}:\\ \\
IC's
\begin{cases} 
 \displaystyle 
u(x,y,0)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}c_{5nm}\sin(n\pi x)\sin(m\pi y)=\sin^2(\pi x)\sin(\pi y) \\ \\
 \displaystyle 
u_{t}(x,y,0)=0 \rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\omega_{nm}c_{6nm}\sin(n\pi x)\sin(m\pi y)=0 \rightarrow \boxed{c_{6nm}=0}
\end{cases}
\end{gather}
$$
but the final solution that the textbook provided as a hint is this:

how am i supposed to transform my solution to this form?

Correct is
$$\require{cancel}u(x,y,t)=-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1,3,4...}^{\infty} \frac{1-(-1)^n}{n\left(n^2-4\right)}\cos\left(\pi c \sqrt{n^2+1}\cdot t\right)\sin(\pi n x)\sin(\pi \color{red}{\cancel{n}} y)$$

With the initial condition
$$u(x,y,0)=f(x,y):=\sin^2(\pi x)\sin(\pi y)$$
the Fourier coefficients $c_{5nm}$ evaluate to
$$c_{5nm}=4\int _0^1\int _0^1 f(x,y)\cdot\sin(n\pi x)\cdot\sin(m\pi y)\; \mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x= -\frac{8\sin(\pi m)(\cos(\pi n)-1)}{\pi^2\left(m^2-1\right) n\left(n^2-4\right)}$$
and
$$c_{5n1}=\underset{m\to 1}{\text{lim}}c_{5nm}=-\frac{4}{\pi}\cdot\frac{1-(-1)^n}{n(n^2-4)}$$
with
$$c_{5nm}=0,\;\; m\ne 1$$
Finally we get for odd $n$:
$$u(x,y,t):=-\frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{n=1,3,5,...}^{\infty} \frac{2}{n(n^2-4)}\cdot \cos(\pi c\sqrt{n^2+1}\cdot t)\cdot\sin(\pi n x)\cdot\sin(\pi y)$$
Visualize


Thanks for your thorough explanation.
